# Redireccionar con Springboot

Tags: html, spring-boot

tengo un frontal con varias opciones, dichas opciones te pueden llevar  a una página web de coches, motos, etc...

En el backEnd, se recoge dicha solicitud por post, se hacen unas operaciones en dicho método y se vuelve a llamar "a si mismo" pero por get para hacer hacer la redirección2.

Aquí el código que va a recibir los datos sensibles y a donde va:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/redirigir")
    public ModelAndView redirigir (@RequestBody Redireccion destino, ModelMap model) throws JsonProcessingException {

        log.info( "--->  SERVICIO DE REDIRECCIÓN");

        printParameters(destino);
        String direccion = "";

        if ("generar".equals(destino.getDestino())) {
            direccion = urlGenerar;
        }

        if ("descarga".equals(destino.getDestino())) {
            direccion = urlDescarga;
        }

        if ("".equals(direccion)) {
            log.error( "--->  El destino no es correcto");

//          return new ResponseEntity<String>("", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } else {
            log.info( "--->  Redirigiendo.");


//          return new ResponseEntity<String>(direccion.concat(destino.getUsuario()), HttpStatus.OK);   
        }
        model.addAttribute("destino", destino);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/gestUsr/redirigir2");
    }
```

Y aquí el código que es llamado por el código anterior PARA LLEVAR A GOOGLE (cuando funcione llevará a donde tiene que llevar.)

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/redirigir2")
    public ModelAndView redirigir2 (ModelMap model) throws JsonProcessingException {

        log.info( "--->  SERVICIO DE REDIRECCIÓN2");
        log.info (model.get("destino"));
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:http://www.google.es");
//          return new ResponseEntity<String>(direccion.concat(destino.getUsuario()), HttpStatus.OK);   
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se hizo de esta manera, (servicio1-POST) llama a (servicio2-Get) porque cuando se intentaba hacer la redirección saltaba el 405 OPTIONS por ser te tipo POST, por eso, se hace la redirección2 desde un servicio que es por GET pero sigue dando problemas.

**Edito:**

He configurado el method para que redirigir2 sea por RequestMethod.PUT y tampoco funciona.

He cambio la url por una url Interna del proyecto (debería gestionar Angular7)

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect:http://localhost:8080/****/pin");
```

El resultado es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Da un bonito 200 y todo lo que tú quieras, pero no hace la redirección, si pongo la url de h`ttp://localhost:8080/****/pin` obviamente si me lleva.

Comment: ¿La llamada original la hace AngularJS?

Comment: si, angular llama al servidor para dejar unos datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si obtienes un HTTP Status 200 pero no se está redirigiendo, esto significa que tu petición es una llamada AJAX. Seguramente, si ves el cuerpo de la respuesta, tengas todo el HTML que forma la web de google.es.

Lo que puedes hacer en este caso es tomar la propiedad [`responseURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseURL) del objeto `XMLHttpRequest`.
Si hay una redirección, esta propiedad tendrá la URL final a la que se han pedido los datos. Puedes obtenerla y actualizar `window.location.href` con dicho valor